# subset of uniform random elements

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $m$ elements that are streamed one by one in a uniform random order. The probability of each element to appear next is $1/m$. We assign an index as the elements are observed. So the first element is 1 and the last element is $m$. We discard some of the elements and retain the rest possibly in a deterministic way. Can we say that the index also induce a uniform random order on the retained element.

Here is an example. Suppose we have 5 elements: $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ streamed in a random order, and let this order be $\{b,d,c,e,a\}$. Say we retain $\{b,d,e\}$ and discard the rest. Can we say that the order of the retained elements are also uniformly distributed?

EDIT: Clarification. The subset of elements depends of the original order. For example, in the previous scenario if the elements were streamed in order $\{c,d,b,a,e\}$, we may have discard c, b and e and the surviving elements would be $\{d,a\}$.

Comment: You seam to be sampling without replacement, i.e. permuting.  If any of the $m!$ permutations are equally likely, and you were always planning to keep the 1st, 2nd and 4th elements independently of the order that appears, then yes: the pattern $(b,d,e)$ has a probability $\frac{(m-3)!}{m!}$ of appearing, as does any other pattern of three distinct elements, so in that sense it is uniformly distributed.

Comment: If each permutation of $\{a, b, c, d, e\}$ is equally likely (with probability $1/5!$), then the orderings of $\{b, d, e\}$ obtained by discarding $a$ and $c$ will each have equal probability $1/3!$, which is the same distribution as if you had only started with $\{b, d, e\}$ and randomly ordered them. Note that I am taking a slightly different interpretation than Henry: I am always keeping $b, d, e$, whereas he is always keeping the 1st, 2nd, and 4th elements. You should confirm which of the two you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In a sense, I meant both. I want to know if we take any subset of elements, the ordering of the elements in the subset is uniformly distributed.